# Python regex for line of digits and optional dash+digits. Why not matching?

Tags: python, regex

I have been struggling with this for an embarrassingly long time so I have come here for help.

I want to match all strings that have a number followed by an optional dash followed by more numbers.

Example:

```
#Match
1
34-1
2-5-2
15-2-3-309-1

# Don't match
1--
--
#$@%^#$@#
dafadf
10-asdf-1
-12-1-
```

I started with this regex (one or more digits, followed optionally by a dash and one and more digits):

```
\d+(-\d+)*
```

That didn't work.  Then I tried parenthesizing around the `\d`:

```
(\d)+(-(\d)+)*
```

That didn't work either.  Can anybody help me out?

Comment: The problem is actually in your definition... you need to be more specific. You specify `1--`, `10-asdf-1`, and (maybe) `-12-1-` as "Don't Match', but at least the first two definitely match your text description, as well as the regex. The regex _does_ match your text description, but not apparently what you really want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(\d+(?:$|(?:-\d+)+))
```

[See it work here](http://regex101.com/r/sA7sR4).

Or, Debugex version of the same regex:

```
^(\d+(?:$|(?:-\d+)+))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UyryWKxAFQKdU9PP)

Perhaps even a better alternative since it is anchored on both ends:

```
^(\d+(?:-\d+)*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hxJQtigkgG86mpfL)

Make sure that you use the right flags and re method:

```
import re

tgt='''
#Match
1
34-1
2-5-2
15-2-3-309-1

# Don't match
1--
--
#$@%^#$@#
dafadf
10-asdf-1
-12-1-
'''

print re.findall(r'^(\d+(?:-\d+)*)$', tgt, re.M)
# ['1', '34-1', '2-5-2', '15-2-3-309-1']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Wow, I did not realize it would be this complicated...

Comment: Actually, it is not that complicated once you can get in the habit of speaking in character group that you want to match: I want to match a line (OK, `^.*$`) that starts with digits (OK, `^\d+$`) and, optionally has a hyphen then more digits (OK, trickiest part, but `^(\d+(?:-\d+)*)$`)

Comment: That's fair.  I actually hadn't even heard of character groups and lookaheads and stuff like that until these answers here.  I'll study them a bit more.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait! One last thing: in your regex, the `?:` bit doesn't seem to be necessary right?  It could've just been: `^(\d+(-\d+)*)$`

Comment: Good catch. That is true, but it makes it a little clearer (IMHO) that you do not intend to capture the `-\d+` groups; only that you want to test for presence or 0 or more with the `*`. It is a matter of style really -- and in Perl at least a matter of slight performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex I constructed that covers all your positive test cases; the ruleset is python:

```
^(?=\d)([-\d]+)*(?<=\d)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/s_oyFE72lqJJt7ER)

Basically, there's a lookahead to make sure it starts with a number at the start. There's a lookbehind to make sure it ends with a number, too, and each capturing group inbetween is consisting strictly of digits and hyphens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Wow, I did not realize it would be this complicated...

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^((?:\d+(?:-|$))+)$
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/sD0oL7

Answer (score 1):

Your original regex seems to work fine for the inputs you've given for examples, with one caveat:  You need to be using either line-begin (^) and line-end($) anchors or specify full-line matching instead of string search which will implicitly use ^ and $ to enclose your regex.  (i.e. re.match() vs. re.search() in Python)

The other examples all work fine, but the ^$ is what's really doing it.

Cheers.